# Issue parsing JSON image url

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse a JSON image url and display it in a view. I have no trouble getting the image url and converting it to `UIImage`. When the user selects a row in the tableview a new view is presented and displays the image from the url. The issue is that the image is different every time the view loads. I `NSLog` the url and it is the same every time I select the row. I can not see where I am going wrong here.

This is the view that gets the image url and converts it to an image:

```
    //  ViewController.m

    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

...
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        //imgURL = [imgURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_url"]];
        //NSLog(@"%@", imageUrl);
        UIImage *barImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]];
        NSLog(@"%@", imageUrl);

        _model.barAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@ %@", [[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"address"],
                             [[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"state"],
                             [[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"zip"]];

        _detailData.selectedBarName = [[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        _detailData.selectedBarAddress = _model.barAddress;
        _detailData.selectedBarPhoneNumber = [[_model.bars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"phone"];
        _detailData.selectedBarImage = barImage;

        NSLog(@"%@", _detailData.selectedBarImage);

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSeg"]) {

            DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            controller.barNameObject = _detailData.selectedBarName;
            controller.barAddressObject = _detailData.selectedBarAddress;
            controller.barPhoneNumberObject = _detailData.selectedBarPhoneNumber;
            controller.barImageObject = _detailData.selectedBarImage;
            NSLog(@"%@", controller.barImageObject);
        }
    }

    @end

This is the view that displays the image.


    //  DetailViewController.m
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewData.h"

    @interface DetailViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation DetailViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];

        //_detailData = [[DetailViewData alloc] init];

        _model = [[Model alloc] init];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

        _barName.text  = self.barNameObject;
        _barAddress.text = self.barAddressObject;
        _barPhone.text = self.barPhoneNumberObject;
        _barPhoto.image = self.barImageObject;

    }
```

Comment: Give code where you are facing problem, Don't post full code. 80% of SO people won't go through like this type of question.

Comment: chek indexPath.row  in - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender  method... if row value is not same.. use another way to get index..like this link....http://pastie.org/1254081

Comment: try using didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method from the table view delegate instead of segue. This way you have the cell they selected directly accessible to you. check the entry in [_model.bars objectAtIndex] is the same data as in the selected row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct.

So, I checked the web service response. If you check any of the image_URl 
say http://lorempixel.com/900/500/sports/?v=-417059871 , it is loading different images all the time. I think the issue is not in your code but in the url, just paste it in your browser and refresh, each time it loads different images.

I wanted to add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation as of now.